# Do ghouls also live outside Japan?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

In the universe of *Tokyo Ghoul*:

- Do ghouls exist only in Japan, or do they thrive in large numbers throughout the world?
- Is there any body such as the CCG in those parts of the world
- Is there any known history of their communication/collaboration with the CCG?

Comment: As someone who just started the series I find this to be interesting. Based off of the descriptions by the people of Aneteiku(if that's how you spell it?). I believe so. They seem to have their own laws, jurisdictions, and ways of life to live among humans after watching episode 4. Though I don't have nearly enough knowledge to post a clear answer. That's what I'm lead to believe

Comment: @kaz-Its spelled Anteiku in English, by the way..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are in fact ghouls outside Japan.

- There's the Chinese terrorist organization, [Chi She Lian](https://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Chi_She_Lian)
- There's also a group in Germany studying ghouls, [Ghoul Forschung Gesellschaft](https://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Ghoul_Forschung_Gesellschaft)
- There's also ghouls from Russia, e.g., [Donato Porpora](https://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Donato_Porpora)

Comment: So do China and Germany and Russia have a counter ghoul organisation such as the CCG ?

Comment: They do, we're not told much about them.

Comment: Quinques were developed by a japanese and a german researcher

Answer (score 0):

I was watching *Tokyo Ghoul:re*, and one of the characters said something that makes you think ghouls reside outside of Japan. He said his time in Germany helped him prepare for this.

So, ghouls may not only exist in Japan, but they may also exist in other countries. Though I am curious to know if that also applies to the CCG, or do they go by another name than in Japan.

It may be me just overthinking things, but maybe some ghouls actually ran away to other countries to escape the CCG.

Answer (score 0):

I read more of the manga and one of the investigators was talking about another investigator, he said:
He was handpicked for the China Investigation Team...
Even there he left his mark against the Chì Shè Liàn (Red Tongue Union Ghouls).
So yes in fact, there are ghouls in China but I'm not sure if they're found anywhere else.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KTZn.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

It's an interesting question, I was reading the manga and one of the main characters said: I can't believe we're in Japan, this reminds me of the Middle East; although it wasn't clear if he said that about the weather or something about ghouls. They were somewhere near the beach with no event going on but I think I saw a dead body there, will try to find the page again and check.